# No MathJax rendering in preview windows.

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax

I am not getting any MathJax rendering at all in my preview windows. Reproducible on two different machines in three different browsers (chrome, firefox, IE, on XP SP3). Clearing the cache doesn't help. I've never seen this problem before. Is preview MathJax rendering working for anyone else?

Comment: Bill, do you have Noscript as a plugin for Chrome/Firefox?  I see the MathJax.org script on the main and view question pages, but it doesn't show on the ask question page.

Comment: @Jason: No, I'm not using Noscript.

Answer (score 5):

This is fixed and will be deployed this evening.  Question Ask was missing a JS reference to the CDN version of MathJax.